# Toshiba Satellite S50-A

Tags: drivers, toshiba

Can I install Ubuntu on this laptop? Where can I get drivers?
http://www.toshiba.com/us/computers/laptops/satellite/S50

Answer (score 0):

Just choose option "try ubuntu" ( without installing ). It is a perfect way to see if everything works. You will probably see you have all drivers with Ubuntu installation and then you can choose to proceed with installation.

Answer (score 0):

How did you configure your computer? I think that everything will work out of the box when installing [Ubuntu 13.10 64 bit](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/thank-you?release=latest&bits=64&distro=desktop&status=zeroc)